# GnuRadio Companion OOT XML Schema Documentation

Tags: gnuradio-companion

GnuRadio companion uses XML files to describe the API for out-of-tree (OOT) module blocks. Where is the documentation that describes that XML schema?

Answer (score 2):

There is a partial description here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GNURadioCompanion#Creating_the_XML_Block_Definition

> - The **name** tags dictate the label text for the block, parameters, and ports.
> - The **key** tags are unique identifiers, they may not contain spaces. The block key must be globally unique among all blocks in GRC. The
>     parameter keys must be unique only within the block.
> - The **category** tag is a unix-style path that represents the location of the block inside the block selection window. The path can be a new
>     category (Custom), or represent a sub-category (Filters/Custom). To
>     put a block into the root category, just use a single slash (/) for
>     the root path.
> - The **import** tag (there can be multiple) must be a valid python import statement to the module containing your block.
> - The **make** tag contains the code necessary to construct your block. This code is essentially a cheetah template nested inside an xml tag.
>     Upon code generation, the template performs a text substitution on the
>     "$" parameters. For more advanced capabilities, see the cheetah
>     template documentation.
> - The **callback** tag registers a set-method from your custom block. Once the set-method is registered, the set-method can be called at runtime
>     when a variable is changed. There can be any number of callback tags,
>     one for each set-method of your block. Or no callback tags if this is
>     not applicable.
> - For the **param** tags, the commonly used values for the type tags are: complex, real, int, complex_vector, real_vector, int_vector, string,
>     and raw. The raw type allows any value to be used without performing
>     type checking. The real type should be used for single and double
>     precision floating point numbers. The int type should be used for
>     longs, ints, shorts, and chars.
> - The **hide** tag controls how the parameter is displayed in GRC. It's either none, part (show in the prop dialog, not in the block on the
>     canvas) or all.
> - The **sink** tag represents an input port, and the **source** tag represents an output port. The allowed values for the type tags are: complex,
>     float, int, short, and byte. For ports with a vector length, specify a
>     vlen tag after the type tag.

In lieu of a better alternative, there is a Document type definition describing the XML for blocks: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/grc/core/block.dtd. The relavant part is shown below:

```
<!--
    Top level element.
    A block contains a name, ...parameters list, and list of IO ports.
 -->
<!ELEMENT block (name, key, category?, throttle?, flags?, import*, var_make?, var_value?,
        make, callback*, param_tab_order?, param*, bus_sink?, bus_source?, check*,
        sink*, source*, bus_structure_sink?, bus_structure_source?, doc?,  grc_source?)>
<!--
    Sub level elements.
 -->
<!ELEMENT param_tab_order (tab+)>
<!ELEMENT param (base_key?, name, key, value?, type?, hide?, option*, tab?)>
<!ELEMENT option (name, key, opt*)>
<!ELEMENT sink (name, type, vlen?, domain?, nports?, optional?, hide?)>
<!ELEMENT source (name, type, vlen?, domain?, nports?, optional?, hide?)>
<!--
    Bottom level elements.
    Character data only.
 -->
```

Wikipedia describes the qualifiers used in the [Document type definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition):

> A quantifier is a single character that immediately follows the
>   specified item it applies to, to restrict the number of successive
>   occurrences of these items at the specified position in the content of
>   the element; it may be either:
>
> - + for specifying that there must be one or more occurrences of the item — the effective content of each occurrence may be different;
> - * for specifying that any number (zero or more) of occurrences is allowed — the item is optional and the effective content of each
>     occurrence may be different
> - ? for specifying that there must not be
>     more than one occurrence — the item is optional;

The **<check>** tag can be used for validation. E.g. if you had a parameter with key "title" and another parameter with key "num", you could use the following top level tags for validation.

```
<check>$title != ""</check>
<check>$num &gt; -1</check>
<check>$num &lt; 5</check>
```