# GRC OOT schema documentation

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm looking for GnuRadio Companion OOT schema documentation. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534857/gnuradio-companion-oot-xml-schema-documentation) and I'm not satisfied. I saw something more like a tutorial about YAML and XML:

```
https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/YAML_GRC
https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/XML_GRC
```

This is definitely not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a place where I can find all possible options and parameters/attributes to set. There aren't e.g. "tab" or "option" parameters for the "param" option from XML over there. I would also like to have something similar for YAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hard to answer in closed form, but essentially, we have a schema checker, and it contains lists of the acceptable YAML properties:

https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/master/grc/core/schema_checker

Comment: don't fully understand the question? go and look into the block.py file I linked to: it contains constructs of allowed properties.

Comment: Okay, now I see it. Is there something similar for gnuradio 3.7 that uses xml? There is no schema_checker directory in maint-3.7

Comment: ... that's XML. XML has DTDs.

Comment: This is definitely YML. There are id and label properties, whose XML equivalents are key and name. Don't I understand something?

Comment: I'm confused. You've asked about 3.7, right? In 3.7, there was no YAML.

Comment: I see that I've expressed myself very vaguely. Essentially, I meant that I found such a program - https://github.com/ptrkrysik/multi-rtl/blob/master/grc/gen_multi_rtl_block.py There are lot of attributes in this code that aren't in the guide, so where did developer get them from?

Comment: Piotr probably read other blocks' XML files and / or the GRC source code