# What does the <tab> attribute mean in gnuradio 3.7 XML and what is its equivalent in 3.8 YML?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to find out what does the `<tab>` attribute mean in gnuradio 3.7 XML and what is its equivalent in 3.8 YML. As I deduced from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030622/grc-oot-schema-documentation), documentation that describes GRC OOT schema attributes probably doesn't exist. I want to change the gnuradio 3.7 XML block generation program so that it generates gnuradio 3.8 YML blocks. However, I do not know what `<tab>` means and what's its equivalent in the YML used by gnuradio 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<tab>` tag inside of `<param>` specifies in which Propertie's tab the parameter is going to be displayed.

For example here is the XML definition of the `Trigger Mode` parameter from `qtgui_const_sink_x.xml`

```
  <param>
    <name>Trigger Mode</name>
    <key>tr_mode</key>
    <value>qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE</value>
    <type>enum</type>
    <hide>part</hide>
    <option>
      <name>Free</name>
      <key>qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE</key>
    </option>
    <option>
      <name>Auto</name>
      <key>qtgui.TRIG_MODE_AUTO</key>
    </option>
    <option>
      <name>Normal</name>
      <key>qtgui.TRIG_MODE_NORM</key>
    </option>
    <option>
      <name>Tag</name>
      <key>qtgui.TRIG_MODE_TAG</key>
    </option>
    <tab>Trigger</tab>
  </param>
```

And here is how it looks like in the GNU Radio Companion when you open the Properties dialog of `QT GUI Constellation Sink` block.

[image]

For gnuradio 3.8 the equivalent parameter is called `category`, here is the YAML definition of the same parameter (from `qtgui_const_sink_x.block.yml`)

```
-   id: tr_mode
    label: Trigger Mode
    category: Trigger
    dtype: enum
    default: qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE
    options: [qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE, qtgui.TRIG_MODE_AUTO, qtgui.TRIG_MODE_NORM, qtgui.TRIG_MODE_TAG]
    option_labels: [Free, Auto, Normal, Tag]
    hide: part
```